# Can a human become demon or viceversa?

Tags: scripture, asuras, rakshasa, demon

Can a human of degraded character become demon or rakshasa? Or can a demon become human through his good character? Justify with refrence of scriptures.

Comment: It can happen but in next life. But not in his life

Comment: Still you can say that one is a demon because he killed someone. But he would become a demon biologically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can a human of degraded character become demon or rakshasa? Or can a demon become human through his good character? Justify with refrence of scriptures.

Yes:

> [Manu 12.39](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc202220.html) - I am now going to describe, briefly, in due order, those migratory states into which one falls through each quality from among these.

> 40 - Those partaking of ‘Sattva’ reach the state of the gods, those endowed with ‘Rajas,’ the state of men, and those characterised by ‘Tamas,’ the state of beasts; such is the threefold migratory state.

> 41 - This threefold Migratory State due to the qualities should be understood to be again of three kinds each—high, low and middling, in accordance with the peculiar character of the act and knowledge of each man.

> 44 - Cāraṇas, Suparṇas, hypocritical men, **Rākṣasas, and Piśācas**—represent the highest state among those partaking of the quality of ‘Tamas.’

Answer (score 4):

> Manu Smriti 12.60. He who has associated with outcasts, he who has
> approached the wives of other men, and he who has stolen the property
> of a Brahmana **become Brahmarakshasas**.

> Can a human of degraded character become demon or rakshasa?

Yes, as shown by the verse given above. But obviously that happens in the next life.

Comment: Only these 3 Sins will Bramharakshasas be born or other things like << a dead scholar of high birth, who has done evil things in his life or has misused his knowledge, who has to suffer as a Brahma Rakshasa after his or her death>> As Wiki claims? Just asking Rickross Ji please dont mind

Comment: May be other scriptures mention about those mentioned in Wikipedia. @SethuSrivatsaKoduru